# kernelmanagerd using 50% of the cpu constantly

Tags: big-sur, kernel-extensions

After upgrading to macOS Big Sur my MacBook Pro 2017 constantly heats up even when it not in use which was not the case before upgrading. I have A MacBook Air which do not have this problem.

When compared `kernelmanagerd` process is constantly using 50% of the CPU in my MacBook Pro in MacBook Air its almost 0%. I have uninstalled all third-party kernel extensions still the problem exists.

Is there any way to find which extension is using the CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem, it is [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/).

Funny thing was I have installed Karabiner-Elements in my mac when it ran macOS High Sierra but I immediately uninstalled (I was trying something with it) but some residue was left behind.

Today when exploring the activity monitor, I noticed some karabiner process was there, so i installed the latest version of Karabiner. Instantly i noticed `kernelmanagerd` CPU usage became 0.0.

Then I uninstalled Karabiner as in [this document](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/operation/uninstall/#:%7E:text=Karabiner%2DElements%20provides%20built%2Din,Elements%E2%80%9D%20button%20on%20Misc%20tab.)

Now my MacBook Pro is normal.